# egit project + branch name huge font on Git Staging tab

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have a second display at work, when I went into the EGit tab I found that the text was too large on the project + branch name. For privacy reasons I edited out the project name bust still left the branch to show what I mean:

[image]

I've tried changing `General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Git` fonts for every option there without result. As well as `General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > View and Editor Folders > Part title font`

Is there anyway to make that text smaller? I mean it takes too much space there

Comment: anything relevant on .log file? may there's a hint there.

Comment: I can tell by tomorrow, that is my job's computer... @LuisMuñoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I just had to restart eclipse after editing:

```
Editor Folders > Part title font
```

That did the trick.